# FFImageLoading CachedImage is not showing gif image

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my app development. I am using FFimageloading for view gif file. I am using the following code in xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myproject.View.MasterDetailPage1Detail"
             Icon="UEmlogotiny.png"
             xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"  
             xmlns:ffSvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"  
             xmlns:ffTransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
             >
```

....

```
<ff:CachedImage x:Name="Gif" Source="resource://UETrack.Beats.App.loader.gif" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75"
                            DownsampleToViewSize="True" IsVisible="True"/>
```

Change the Image Build Action to "Embedded Resource"

The gif image has showed on Orio. But not show in below Oreo.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you add your image? To the Drawable folders? xxhdpi, etc?

If so,you can simple do:

```
Source="loader.gif"
```